# Is there a way to bootstrap a Kotlin project from the command line?

Tags: kotlin

Currently if one need to start a new Kotlin project options are either Android Studio or IntelliJ IDEA.
I need to be able to bootstrap a Kotlin project from the command line without using any IDE, e.g. run a command as below:

```
kotlinc create <project_name>
```

Is there a way I can do this and have all the necessary files created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide.html).
For this you need to install a JDK and Gradle.

With the [`init`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_init_plugin.html#sec:kotlin_application) Task you can create different application types:

```
gradle init --type kotlin-application --dsl kotlin
```